Find minimum of $G = (x^3+y^3+z^3)\left(\frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{1}{y^3}+\frac{1}{z^3}\right)$
Let $x, y, z > 0$ and $$(x+y+z)\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}\right)=11$$Find minimum of $$G = (x^3+y^3+z^3)\left(\frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{1}{y^3}+\frac{1}{z^3}\right)$$
I have no ideas for this problem, maybe $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)$ is useful
$$G = 3+\frac{x^3}{y^3}+\frac{y^3}{z^3}+\frac{z^3}{x^3}+\frac{y^3}{x^3}+\frac{x^3}{z^3}+\frac{z^3}{y^3}$$
We can't directly apply the AM-GM inequality because the equation case would be $x=y=z$, which does not satisfy the assumption.

Can't you just use Langrange multipliers?

@KonradSzałwiński: Have you tried that yourself? If not, please do!

The command of Mathematica 14 Minimize[{(x^3 + y^3 + z^3)*(1/x^3 + 1/y^3 + 1/z^3), {x, y, z} >      0 && (x + y + z)*(1/x + 1/y + 1/z) == 11}, {x, y, z}] answers $$ \left{41,\left{x\to 1,y\to \frac{1}{2} \left(3-\sqrt{5}\right),z\to \frac{5 \left(3-\sqrt{5}\right)}{4 \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(3-\sqrt{5}\right)+1\right)}-\frac{\sqrt{\frac{9}{4} \left(3-\sqrt{5}\right)^2-6 \left(3-\sqrt{5}\right)+4}}{2 \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(3-\sqrt{5}\right)+1\right)}\right}\right}.$$

Define
$$a=\sum\frac{x}{y}, b=\sum\frac{y}{x}, p=\sum\frac{x^2}{yz}, q=\sum\frac{yz}{x^2}$$
to have $a+b=8$, $ab=p+q+3$ and
$a^3+b^3=\sum\frac{x^3}{y^3}+\sum\frac{y^3}{x^3}+6p+6q+12$.
This gives
\begin{align*}
\left(\sum x^3\right) \left(\sum\frac 1{x^3}\right) & =\sum\frac{x^3}{y^3}+\sum\frac{y^3}{x^3}+3 \\
& = a^3+b^3-6p-6q-9 \\
& = a^3+b^3-6ab+9 \\
& \ge \frac 14 (a+b)^3-\frac 32(a+b)^2+9 \\
& = 128-96+9=41
\end{align*}
hence completing the proof.

I'm sorry, did you mean $(\sum x^3) (\sum 1/x^3)$ or $\sum x^3 \sum 1/x^3$?

@Snared of course not the double sum! I will make the edit.

We suppose $x,y,z$ are the three positive roots of the cubic equation
$$t^3 -pt^2+qt-r =0$$
According to this result, $(p,q,r) =(x+y+z,xy+yz+zx,xyz)$ must satisfy these following contraints
$$\begin{align}
-27r^2 &+ 18 pqr - 4 q^3 - 4 p^3 r + p^2 q^2 \ge 0 \tag{1}\\
&p,q,r\ge 0\tag{2}
\end{align}$$
We have
$$(x+y+z)\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}\right)=11 \iff pq=11r \tag{3}$$
then
$$\begin{align}
(1)&\iff-27r^2+18\cdot11r\cdot r-4(q^3 +p^3r)+11^2r^2 \ge0\\
&\iff q^3 +p^3r\le 73r^2 \tag{4}
\end{align}$$
and from $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)$, we can easily deduce that
$$\begin{align}
&x^3 +y^3 + z^3 = p(p^2 -3q)+3r\\
&\frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{1}{y^3}+\frac{1}{z^3} = \frac{q(q^2-3rp)+3r^2}{r^3} \tag{5}
\end{align}$$
From $(3),(5)$, we have:
$$\begin{align}
G &= (x^3+y^3+z^3)\left(\frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{1}{y^3}+\frac{1}{z^3}\right)\\
&= \frac{(p(p^2 -3q)+3r)(q(q^2-3rp)+3r^2)}{r^3}\\
&= \frac{(p^3 -30r)(q^3 -30r^2)}{r^3}\\
&=\frac{(pq)^3 +900r^3-30r(rp^3 + q^3)}{r^3}\\
G&=\frac{2231r^3 -30r(rp^3 + q^3)}{r^3}\\
\end{align}$$
From $(4)$, we have:
$$\color{red}{G = \frac{2231r^3 -30r(rp^3 + q^3)}{r^3} \ge \frac{2231r^3 -30r\cdot 73r^2}{r^3} = 41}$$
The equality occurs if and only if the positive variables $(p,w,r)$ satisfy
$$\cases{&$pq = 11r$\\
&$rp^3 +q^3 = 73r^2$} \tag{6}$$
It is easy to solve $(6)$, we have two solutions $(rp^3,q^3) = \left( \frac{73-\sqrt{5}}{2}r^2 ,\frac{73+\sqrt{5}}{2}r^2\right)$ and $(rp^3,q^3) = \left( \frac{73+\sqrt{5}}{2}r^2 ,\frac{73-\sqrt{5}}{2}r^2\right)$.

If $\cases{rp^3 = \frac{73-\sqrt{5}}{2}r^2\\q^3 = \frac{73+\sqrt{5}}{2}r^2}$, then $\cases{p = \left(\frac{73-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{1/3}r^{1/3}\\q = \left(\frac{73+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{1/3}r^{2/3}}$
Solve the cubic equation
$$t^3 - \left(\frac{73-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{1/3}r^{1/3}t^2 +\left(\frac{73+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{1/3}r^{2/3}t - r = 0 $$
$$\iff \left(\frac{t}{r^{1/3}} \right)^3- \left(\frac{73-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{1/3}\left(\frac{t}{r^{1/3}} \right)^2 +\left(\frac{73+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{1/3}\left(\frac{t}{r^{1/3}} \right) - 1 = 0 \tag{7}$$
The equation $(7)$ has three positive roots $t_1 =\left(\frac{2}{3+\sqrt{5}}\right)^{2/3}, t_2 = t_3  =\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{2/3}$, then
$$\color{red}{(x,y,z) = (\alpha t_1,\alpha t_2,\alpha t_3) \hspace{1cm} \forall \alpha >0 } \tag{8}$$
(of course, the value of three variables $x,y,z$ can be permuted)

If $\cases{rp^3 = \frac{73-\sqrt{5}}{2}r^2\\q^3 = \frac{73+\sqrt{5}}{2}r^2}$, then $\cases{p = \left(\frac{73+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{1/3}r^{1/3}\\q = \left(\frac{73-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{1/3}r^{2/3}}$
By similar technique, we have
$$\color{red}{(x,y,z) = (\alpha t_4,\alpha t_5,\alpha t_6) \hspace{1cm} \forall \alpha >0 } \tag{9}$$
with $t_4 =\left(\frac{2}{3-\sqrt{5}}\right)^{2/3}, t_5 = t_6  =\left(\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{2/3}$
(the value of three variables $x,y,z$ can be permuted)

Conclusion: $G\ge 41$ and the equality occurs if and only if $(x,y,z)$ satisfy $(8)$ or $(9)$.

Sorry, I was too hasty. It all looked so arbitrary. But I've managed to verify most of it, so I retract my comment. +1 :-)

@TonyK I just completed the answer. And thank you for the upvote!

@NN2 Nice. The minimum is still $41$ if we replace $(x+y+z)(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z})=11$ with $(x+y+z)(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z})\ge 11$. Does your approach still work? In particular, in (4), you replace $pq$ by $11r$ in (1) to obtain $-27r^2+18\cdot11r\cdot r-4(q^3 +p^3r)+11^2r^2 \ge0$. Now, it becomes $pq \ge 11r$, it seems we can not do that directly.

@RiverLi Of course, if we replace the condition like this, the approach still works as follows. First, $$(1)\implies q^3 + p^3 r\le -\frac{27}{4}r^2 + \frac{9}{2} pqr  + \frac{1}{4}p^2 q^2$$Then
$$G =\frac{2231r^3 -30r(rp^3 + q^3)}{r^3}\ge \frac{(pq)^3  - \frac{15}{2}(pq)^2r - 135(pq)r^2+\frac{2025}{2}r^3}{r^3}$$
Denote $u = pq$, for $u \ge 11r$ , it's easy to prove that : $$\color{red}{u^3 - \frac{15}{2}u^2r - 135ur^2+\frac{2025}{2}r^3 \ge 41r^3} \iff  (u-11 r) \underbrace{(2 u^2+7 r u  - 193 r^2 )}_{\ge 0 \text{ if }u\ge 11r} \ge 0$$
As a consequence
$$G\ge \frac{41r^3}{r^3} = 41$$

Let $p=\displaystyle\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac xy=\left(\frac xy+\frac yz+\frac zx\right)$ and $q=\displaystyle\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac yx=\left(\frac yx+\frac xz+\frac zy\right)$.
Then, we can write
$$p^3=\displaystyle\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac {x^3}{y^3}+3\displaystyle\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac {x^2}{yz}+3\displaystyle\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac {yz}{x^2}+6\tag{1}$$
$$q^3=\displaystyle\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac {y^3}{x^3}+3\displaystyle\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac {x^2}{yz}+3\displaystyle\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac {yz}{x^2}+6\tag{1}$$
$$pq=3+\displaystyle\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac {x^2}{yz}+\displaystyle\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac {yz}{x^2}\tag{2}$$
From $(1),\ (2),$ and $(3)$,
$$\displaystyle\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac {x^3}{y^3}+\displaystyle\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac {y^3}{x^3}=p^3+q^3-6(pq-3)-12=p^3+q^3-6pq+6\tag{3}$$
We have,
$$(x+y+z)\left(\frac1x+\frac1y+\frac1z\right)=3+p+q=11\implies p+q=8\tag{4}$$
We can express $G$ as follows:
$$G=(x^3+y^3+z^3)\left(\frac1{x^3}+\frac1{y^3}+\frac1{z^3}\right)=3+\displaystyle\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac {x^3}{y^3}+\displaystyle\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac {y^3}{x^3}=p^3+q^3-6pq+9\tag{5}$$
The minimum value of $G$ can be determined using the AM–GM inequality as follows:
$$\begin{aligned}G&=(p+q)^3-3pq(p+q)-6pq+9\\&=8^3-3pq\cdot8-6pq+9\\&=521-30pq\qquad\text{note that $G_\text{min}\Leftrightarrow  (pq)_\text{max}$}\\&\geq521-30\left(\frac{p+q}{2}\right)^2\qquad\text{since } \sqrt{pq}\leq\frac{p+q}2\\&=521-30\left(\frac82\right)^2\\G_\text{min}&=41\end{aligned}$$
Hence, the minimum of $G$ is $41$.
Hope this helps!
Also, check my solution to find the maximum value of $G$.

Nice. Letting $p = x/y + y/z + z/x, q = y/x + z/y + x/z$ is another way to deal with some kind of problems, besides pqr.

Given, $$(a + b + c)(\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c}) = 11$$
From Power mean inequality,
$$(\frac{a^3 + b^3 + c^3}{3})^{\frac{1}{3}} > \frac{a + b + c}{3} => (a^3 + b^3 + c^3) > \frac{1}{9}(a + b + c)^3$$
Similarly, $$(\frac{1}{a^3} + \frac{1}{b^3} + \frac{1}{c^3}) > \frac{1}{9}(\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c})^3$$
Therefore, $$(\frac{a^3 + b^3 + c^3}{3})(\frac{1}{a^3} + \frac{1}{b^3} + \frac{1}{c^3}) > \frac{1}{81}((a + b + c)(\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c}))^3 = \frac{11^3}{81}$$
Hence, $G > \frac{11^3}{81}$ .

Nevermind I get it now, why a.m.-g.m.-h.m. of no much use here i thought this would lead to a minimum value but this is not possible this way due to the strictness as $a ≠ b ≠ c$ but i m sure there would be some other ways via classical inequalities for sure it's just lil difficult to figure out

Alternative solution.
Remark. Here I give a solution using the equal variable trick.
This trick works for finding the minimum $(x^4+ y^4 + z^4)(1/x^4 + 1/y^4 + 1/z^4)$ etc. in a similar manner.
First, we claim that at minimum, two of $x, y, z$ are equal. Assume, for the sake of contradiction, that at minimum, $x < y < z$.
Since $(x + y + z)(1/x + 1/y + 1/z) > 9$ (easy), there exists $a, b > 0$ such that
$$(x + y + z)(1/x + 1/y + 1/z) - 5 =  2(a/b + b/a), \tag{1}$$
which results in
$$(x + y + z)(1/x + 1/y + 1/z) = (a + a + b)(1/a + 1/a + 1/b).\tag{2}$$
Using (1), we have
\begin{align*}
 &(x^3 + y^3 + z^3)(1/x^3 + 1/y^3 + 1/z^3) - (a^3 + a^3 + b^3)(1/a^3 + 1/a^3 + 1/b^3)\\
 ={}&(x^3 + y^3 + z^3)(1/x^3 + 1/y^3 + 1/z^3) - 5 - 2(a^3/b^3 + b^3/a^3)\\
 ={}&(x^3 + y^3 + z^3)(1/x^3 + 1/y^3 + 1/z^3) - 5 
 - 2(a/b + b/a)^3 + 6(a/b + b/a)\\
 ={}& (x^3 + y^3 + z^3)(1/x^3 + 1/y^3 + 1/z^3) - 5 \\
 &\quad - \frac{[(x + y + z)(1/x + 1/y + 1/z) - 5]^3}{4} + 3\left[(x + y + z)(1/x + 1/y + 1/z) - 5\right]\\
 ={}& \frac{3(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)(x-y)^2(y-z)^2(z-x)^2}{4x^3y^3z^3}\\
 >{}& 0.
\end{align*}
So, if we replace $x, y, z$ with $a, a, b$ satisfying (2), we have a strictly smaller objective value.
This contradicts the optimality of $(x, y, z)$.
Then, WLOG, we can assume that $x = y = 1$ (since the expressions are homogeneous). We have
$(2 + z)(2 + 1/z) = 11$ i.e. $z + 1/z = 3$
which has two real solutions $z = \frac{3 + \sqrt{5}}{2}, \frac{3 - \sqrt{5}}{2}$.
We have
$$(2 + z^3)(2 + 1/z^3) = 5 + 2(z^3 + 1/z^3)
= 5 + 2(z + 1/z)^3 - 6(z + 1/z) = 41.$$
The minimum is $41$ when $x = y = 1$ and $z = \frac{3 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$.
